# How to solve initial value problem (problem written below)?

Tags: integration

I usually know how to solve an initial value problem (move dx over to the side with the x variables and move y over to the dy side, then integrate both sides and solve), but this problem confused me.

[image]

All of the questions i have encountered are dx/dt questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no tricks here.  You have the fourth derivative of $y$ with respect to $t$ is equal to a function of $t$.  Simply integrate both sides four times.  For example, the first step is

$$y'''=\cos t+\sin t+C$$
$$y'''(0)=7=\cos 0+\sin 0+C,C=6$$

Now continue $3$ more times.

Comment: oh ohmygod ok! thank you so much! so that's what they want me to do! thank you so much!